# Hashicorp Vault: Write secret file then read it again?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

We have a need to store a Java KeyStore file in Hashicorp Vault.  I was able to write the file just fine with a command something like:

```
vault write -address ${VAULT_ADDR} ${SECRET_PATH} keystore=@myKeys.keystore
```

It worked fine, and I got a success message.  I'm also able to list the credentials at that path and see that it was written.  However, how do I get the value back out as a Java Keystore file?  The `vault read` command seems to output yaml or JSON only.  The value in the JSON file does not seem to be base-64 encoded.  How do I get it to output the raw binary value so I can read it as a Java KeyStore?

Answer (score 0):

Your keystore is in binary format... There might an encoding issue. Try this instead:

```
vault write -address {$VAULT_ADDR} ${SECRET_PATH} keystore=$(openssl base64 -A -in myKeys.keystore)
```

And get it back with

```
vault read -address {$VAULT_ADDR} --field keystore ${SECRET_PATH} | openssl base64 -d -A > myKeys.keystore
```

But **a Java keystore is already encrypted**... Why don't you use Vautl for password management? Perfect use case for this:

1. Use Vault to [generate a high-entropy, easy to share password that is easy to rotate](https://serverfault.com/a/931972/81170).
2. Set it as your keystore password
3. Distribute the encrypted keystore as you see fit
4. Whatever receices the keystore calls Vault to get the exact same password you had at step one (using the exact same command).